# convert string to long triggerAtMilli

Tags: android, request, alarmmanager

I am developing an **alarm** and I need to retrieve times from a database.
The code explains how I iterate through my database and retrieve the hour and minutes and then set it in calendar.

How can I set that function to always be working and looping in my database to compare with the current time and then ring?

what about `requestcode`? I have read that it's important and I should take the id of the row in my database and put it `requestcode`.

```
  private void ringalarms(){
        Cursor data = myDB.getListContents();
        int  hr,mt = 0;
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        final Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.context, Alarm_Receiver.class);


        data.moveToFirst();
        while (!data.isAfterLast()) {
            hr=Integer.parseInt(data.getString(0));
            mt=Integer.parseInt(data.getString(1));

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hr);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, mt);



            myIntent.putExtra("extra", "yes");
            //myIntent.putExtra("id", i);


            pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Add_Alarm.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pending_intent);




            data.moveToNext();
        }

    }
```

and

```
  public Cursor getListContents(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT Hour, Minutes FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: You can use service

Comment: please do not change the title and description of your question to something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variety of options for scheduling a background task.

For more info look into [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) and [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)